# MVC, MockMvc, ModelAttribute issue upgrading to Spring 6 / SB3

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mockmvc, modelattribute, spring-mvc-test

Having upgraded an existing SB app from Java 11, Spring 5, SB 2 to Java 17, Spring 6, SB 3 i have an issue i simply cant figure out with the tests. We have a controller which contains a bunch of @ModelAttrbite annotations such as :

```
@ModelAttribute("cdnBucketPath")
public Message<String> getCDNBucketPath() {
    return new GenericMessage<>(CDN_BUCKET_PATH.getValue());
}
```

We then have a test class configured like this :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
@EnableWebSecurity
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class LoginControllerTest extends AbstractControllerTest {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        mvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .apply(documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation))
                .alwaysDo(document(
                        "{method-name}/{step}/",
                        preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()),
                        preprocessResponse(prettyPrint())))
                .build();
    }
...
}
```

We have a series of tests such as :

```
@Test
@WithStringUserPrincipal
@WithMockUser
public void getSession_UserAuthPresent() throws Exception {
    MvcResult result = mvc.perform(get(LOGIN_ENDPOINT)
            .with(admin())
            .with(csrf()))
            .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
            .andReturn();

    ModelAndView modelAndView = result.getModelAndView();

    assertEquals("redirect:http://localhost:7012/", modelAndView.getViewName());

    Message<String> loginUrl = (Message<String>) modelAndView.getModel().get("loginUrl");
    assertEquals(MOCK_IDP_LOGIN_URL, loginUrl.getPayload());
}
```

What we're seeing since upgrading is that the Model in the ModelAndView is not getting populated with the various @ModelAttribute values in the controller above.

I know the test is issuing the controller request just fine so, as far as i can see from docs, the request should trigger the addition of the model attributes. Is there something extra i need to do (or do differently) having upgraded?

Thanks very much

Martin